# arcTo sometimes doesn't get drawn on resize

Tags: javascript, canvas, qml

I have the following QML file that draws a green circle (via a QML Rectangle) and draws a black arc (via Canvas and arcTo) on the circle. The position and radius of the circle depend on the size of the window. For most sizes this seems to work perfectly fine but for some the arc just vanishes. The complete main.qml to reproduce the behaviour is the following:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    height: 400
    width: 400
    Rectangle{
        x:20
        y:20
        height: parent.height-40
        width: parent.width-40

        Rectangle{
            id:circle
            x:(parent.height<parent.width?parent.height:parent.width)/3
            y:x
            height:(parent.height<parent.width?parent.height:parent.width)/3
            width: height
            radius: height/2
            border.color: 'green'
        }

        Canvas{
            anchors.fill: parent
            visible: true
            onPaint: {
                var ctx = getContext("2d");
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                ctx.lineWidth = 4;
                var x = circle.x;
                var y = circle.y;
                var r = circle.radius;
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(x,y+r);
                ctx.arcTo(x,y+2*r,x+r,y+2*r,r);
                ctx.stroke();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The question of course is if this is a bug within QML or if I made an error somewhere. I hope someone can help me there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me. It seems to have something to do with the coordinates passed in:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    height: 400
    width: 400

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 20

        Canvas {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onPaint: {
                var ctx = getContext("2d")
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'black'
                ctx.lineWidth = 4
                var x = 0
                var y = 0
                var r = parent.height / 2
                ctx.beginPath()
                // Visible:
                ctx.moveTo(120.33333333333333, 180.5)
                ctx.arcTo(120.33333333333333, 240.66666666666666, 180.5, 240.66666666666666, 60.166666666666664)
                // Not visible:
//                ctx.moveTo(120.66666666666667, 181)
//                ctx.arcTo(120.66666666666667, 241.33333333333334, 181, 241.33333333333334, 60.333333333333336)
                ctx.stroke()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added a Math.floor to my coordinates to solve the issue:
       var x = Math.floor(circle.x);
       var y = Math.floor(circle.y);
       var r = Math.floor(circle.radius);

Comment: @ralgrad, it's good that you found a workaround. Could you also create a bug report?

Comment: I think the whole problem is a rounding issue in JavaScript and if the values get rounded the wrong way the arc can't be drawn anymore.