# QML Canvas skips path segments when using arcTo with non-zero radius

Tags: qt, html5-canvas, qml

I am trying to paint a simple shape with the QML `Canvas` element. To give the shape rounded edges without having to do manual trigonometry I am using the `arcTo` function. But for some reason `arcTo` with a non-zero radius skips some segments. The exact result depends on radius, width, and height. The result is always correct when using a zero radius.

The result is always one of the following and it is always consistent for a given set of parameters. The behaviour is present in both Qt 5 and 6.

- [Correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zX7w2.png)
- [Fail state #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OacxB.png)
- [Fail state #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Y5C8.png)
- [Fail state #3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lhhn.png)

I have been trying to get this to also break with a browser and an HTML5 canvas element, but so far to no avail. So my question is this: Am I doing something wrong or is the Qt implementation of `arcTo` borked?

Minimal reproducible example:

```qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    id: window

    width: 800
    height: 480
    visible: true

    RowLayout {
        GridLayout {
            columns: 2

            Label { text: "width" }
            Slider {
                id: widthSlider
                from: 0; to: 500
                value: canvas.implicitWidth
            }

            Label { text: "height" }
            Slider {
                id: heightSlider
                from: 0; to: 500
                value: canvas.implicitHeight
            }

            Label { text: "radius" }
            Slider {
                id: radiusSlider
                from: 0; to: 12
            }
        }

        Canvas {
            id: canvas

            implicitWidth: 200
            implicitHeight: 40

            width: widthSlider.value
            height: heightSlider.value

            property real radius: radiusSlider.value
            onRadiusChanged: requestPaint()

            onPaint: {
                let ctx = getContext("2d");
                ctx.reset();

                let pts = [
                        {x: width, y: height, r: radius},
                        {x: 10, y: height, r: radius},
                        {x: 0, y: height/2, r: radius},
                        {x: 10, y: 0, r: radius},
                        {x: width, y: 0, r: radius},
                        {x: width, y: height/2, r: 0},
                    ];

                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(pts[pts.length - 1].x, pts[pts.length - 1].y);

                for (let i = 0; i < pts.length - 1; i++) {
                    ctx.arcTo(
                                pts[i].x, pts[i].y,
                                pts[i + 1].x, pts[i + 1].y,
                                pts[i].r);
                }

                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fill();

                ctx.beginPath();
                for (let j = 0; j < pts.length; j++) {
                    ctx.ellipse(pts[j].x - 5, pts[j].y - 5, 10, 10);
                }
                ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just found a bug report from 6 years ago, which is probably about the very same issue. I'll leave the question posted. Maybe someone here knows some way around it... https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-49049

Comment: That bug report also refers to another [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33303122).